# How to abort Jenkins pipeline build if label is not matched

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile multibranch pipeline script, which runs on two different Jenkins systems. Jenkinsfile relies on a specific label name. In one of the systems, the label based agent is available and in another not (intentionally). In the former it runs fine. In the Jenkins system without the matching label, the job just hangs because it cant find a matching agent.

Is there a way to specify an option to abort (or not start) a build if a label is not found?

Comment: How do you pass a label name to Jenkinsfile?

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko our Jenkinsfile looks like this:

```pipeline { 
  agent { label 'my-build-node-1' }
}
```
This label refers to a docker image, which is available in one Jenkins, but not another. (its intentional) and I want to see if there is a way to reject the build if label not found.

Comment: not sure if it is possible in declarative pipeline but you definitely can do that in scripted pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Some discussion here:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35905

Might not be possible anytime soon

If they are calling in to a shared library then you can check for label being online/available and then fail the build

```
def computers = Jenkins.instance.computers
for(computer in computers){
       if(computer.isOnline()){
            labelStr = computer.node.getLabelString()
       }
       if labelStr ~= /user input/
           break;
}
System.exit(1); // no label
```

Answer (score 0):

For a declarative pipeline it *may* be possible to use `when{beforeAgent}` to test whether a label exists.

This would only be useful where the `agent` is specified for a `stage` rather than the whole pipeline.

*...and caveat that this is an as yet untested hypothesis.*

Comment: Anyone tested the idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just a workaround, but in order to avoid dependency on shared lib I run the below every X minutes to clean-up culprits from queue:

```
import hudson.model.*

def q = Jenkins.instance.queue

q.items.each { 
  if (it =~ /someregex or match all/) {
    why = it.getWhy() 
    if (why =~ /.*There are no nodes with the label.*/) {
        println "No node found for $it.task.runId. It's stuck in damn jenkins queue forever and ever. Killing it"
        q.cancel(it.task)
    }
  }
}
```